# React ForwardRef: Property 'current' does not exist on type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-ref, react-forwardref

I am trying to create a component that will track the vertical scroll. The catch is – the actual scroll container is not easily predictable (in this specific case it is neither `window`, `document` nor `body` – it is `div#__next`, due to CSS overflow rules).

I want to keep the component flexible and self-contained. So I've created a `ref` with DOM selector as an argument. I know it is far from idiomatic (to say the least), but it suprisingly seems to be working:

```
// Parent component
import { useRef } from "react"

const Article = (props) => {
  const scrollContainerRef = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(
    document.querySelector("#__next") // <-- the scroll container reference
  )

  return (
    <SomeContent>
      <ScrollToTop treshold={640} ref={scrollContainerRef} />
    </SomeContent>
)
```

```
// ScrollToTop
const ScrollToTop = forwardRef(
  ({ treshold }, ref) => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {

      if (ref?.current) {
        ref.current.addEventListener("scroll", throttle(toggleVisible, 300))
        return () => {
          ref.current.removeEventListener("scroll", throttle(toggleVisible, 300))
        }
      }
    }, [])
// …
```

**So what's the problem? the current one is Typescript**. I've spent hours trying to get the types right, but to no avail. The parent component is red squigly lines free (unless I pass `globalThis`, which seems to work at least in CodeSandbox), but the `ScrollToTop` is compaining whenever I am accessing `current` property:

```
Property 'current' does not exist on type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLElement>'.
```

I've tried to use `React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null /* or other T's */>`, both in parent and in child, but it didn't help.

Any ideas how to get the types to match? Or is this a silly idea from the beginning?

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-ljw32?file=/src/ScrollToTop.tsx)

Comment: Here is an excellent cheatsheet on React and TypeScript for Refs. There are some differences to your code lite  React.createRef<HTMLDivElement> instead of<HTMLElement>. Don't know what element type your scrollContainerRef has.

https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forward_and_create_ref

Comment: @bödvar Thank you. I am  aware of the React/TypeScript cheat sheet. The `scrollContainerRef` is shown to be `React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement>` when hovering over. But if I try to use that in the child component, I got errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refs *might* be objects with a `.current` property, but they might also be functions. So you can't assume that a forwarded ref has a `.current` property.

I think it's a mistake to use `forwardRef` at all here. The purpose of `forwardRef` is to allow a parent component to get access to an element in a child component. But instead, the parent is the one finding the element, and then you're passing it to the child for it to use. I would use a regular state and prop for that:

```
const Article = (props) => {
  const [scrollContainer, setScrollContainer] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(() => {
    return document.querySelector("#__next");
  });

  return (
    <SomeContent>
      <ScrollToTop treshold={640} scrollContainer={scrollContainer} />
    </SomeContent>
)

interface ScrollToTopProps {
  treshold: number;
  scrollContainer: HTMLElement | null;
}

const ScrollToTop = ({ treshold, scrollContainer }: ScrollToTopProps) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollContainer) {
      const toggle = throttle(toggleVisible, 300);
      scrollContainer.addEventListener("scroll", toggle);
      return () => {
        scrollContainer.removeEventListener("scroll", toggle);
      }
    }
  }, [scrollContainer]);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try. I probably want to use `ref` to add flexibility (use whatever parent send), but it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm without any TS complaints.

Comment: Technically you answered the posters question, but you didn't explain how to fix the type error, which means your answer is helpful to nobody else but the poster.

Comment: @JohnMiller thank you for the feedback. Feel free to edit the answer to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

When using `forwardRef` the type of the ref argument is:

```
type ForwardedRef<T> = ((instance: T | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<T | null> | null;
```

Meaning the ref can be (1) a function, (2) a mutable object with `current` property or (3) null.

If you are sure your instance is `MutableRefObject` just use casting.

```
const MyInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, MyProps>((props, ref) => {
  ...
  const inputRef = ref as MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  const inputText = ref.current.value;
  ...

  return <Input ref={ref} ...>;
});
```

P.S Please note that using `as` isn't type safe, so if you aren't sure what is the type of ref, some type checking is required.